# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected argument 'executable_path'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute this script , it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path.
```

What's the solution please ?

```
HOW_MANY = int(input("How many comments you want to like (0-20):"))

while HOW_MANY > 20:
    print("Cant like more than 20 comments, please choose a smaller number!")
    HOW_MANY = int(input("How many comments you want to like (0-20):"))


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={os.getcwd()}\\profile")
mobile_emulation = {
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
}
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"
)
bot = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=CM().install())
bot.set_window_position(0, 0)
bot.set_window_size(414, 936)

url_file = open("urls.txt", "r")
urls = url_file.readlines()


def doesnt_exist(bot, xpath):
    try:
        bot.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return True
    else:
        return False


for url in urls:
    print("--Liking comments for this post: " + url)

    bot.get(url)

    if not doesnt_exist(bot, "/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"):
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]").click()
        print("Closed pop ups")
    else:
        print("No pop up window.")

    # pause
    time.sleep(4)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div'
    ).click()

    # click on comments
    time.sleep(1)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]'
    ).click()
    time.sleep(2)

    try:
        l_buttons = bot.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div"
        )

        for l_button in l_buttons[:HOW_MANY]:
            l_button.click()
            time.sleep(1)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Couldnt like, comments are disabled.")

print("FINISHED")
bot.quit()
```

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In selenium version `4.10.0` and above, `executable_path` has been deprecated. See below:

[image]

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

**Solution:** You need to use `Service` class now if you want to use `executable_path`. Sample code is as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='C:\\..\\<full path>\\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()
```